# I'm getting a syntax error for the date created_on for Postgresql

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date

I am trying to insert the date it was created on into a table and I'm getting an error, here is the code:

```
const cs = 'site';

const client = new Pool({
  cs,
  user: 'user',
  host: 'host',
  database: 'database',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
//to get rid of the T
var d = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, " ");
//to get rid of the .Z something
var e= d.substr(0, 19);
console.log(e);
const value= `INSERT INTO price(created_on,something1, something2)VALUES(${e},1,1)`;
client.query(
 value,
  (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
    client.end();
  }
);
```

when I look at the result in the console it says 2021-03-14 16:25:05, yet it gives me a

> error: syntax error at or near "16"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Log the value of `value` to the console to see what is being passed - notice the lack of quotes. You should really be using SQL parameters to pass the values to be inserted.

Comment: What driver are you using? Pretty sure the problem is here: `${e}`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. 
>You should really be using SQL parameters to pass the values to be inserted.
What do you mean?

Comment: @pete Whatever `client.query` is, it should have an overload that allows you to pass the parameters separately from the query. It helps prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to quote the date value :

```
const value= `INSERT INTO price(created_on,something1, something2)VALUES('${e}',1,1)`;
```